# How to manually add Qt QML library?

Tags: qt, plugins, static, import, qml

Problem description:
I build Qt 4.8.4 statically and open the ShaderEffects example

```
Application Output:
Run C: \ Qt \ 4.8.3 \ examples \ declarative \ shadereffects \ release \ shadereffects.exe ...
file :/ / / C :/ Qt/4.8.3/examples/declarative/shadereffects/qml/shadereffects/main.qml: 43:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "Qt.labs.shaders": Unknown error import Qt . labs.shaders 1.0 ^
C: \ Qt \ 4.8.3 \ examples \ declarative \ shadereffects \ release \ shadereffects.exe exited with code 0
```

All *.a files exists. 
Thank you!